# Rtmpdumper throwing error

Tags: download, streaming, video-streaming, file-download, rtmp

I am trying to download these videos for my exams from a site, but I keep getting:

```
RTMPDump v2.4 GIT-2015-12-14 (Compiled by KSV)
(c) 2010 Andrej Stepanchuk, Howard Chu, The Flvstreamer Team; license: GPL
Connecting ...
INFO: Connected...
ERROR: Closing connection: NetStream.Play.StreamNotFound
```

Here is the command I tried:

```
rtmpdump -v -r  "rtmps://53c7c8e287199.streamlock.net/vods3/mp4:amazons3/coursekart/videos/1521/topics/ER Diagrams - Part 1 of 1_qtp.mp4" -W "http://d2190hpfa85jkd.cloudfront.net/v11/student/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf" -o "DBMS1.flv"
```

Here is the page source code: 
http://pastebin.com/raw/iJpRfJh6

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong ? and how I can download the videos?

Answer (score 0):

Okay progress, 
I was able to solve it and now I get 5 seconds of the 1 hour video:

```
rtmpdump -r "rtmps://53c7c8e287199.streamlock.net/vods3/" -W "http://d2190hpfa85jkd.cloudfront.net/v11/student/swf/flowplayer-3.2.18.swf"  -y "mp4:amazons3/coursekart/videos/1521/topics/ER Diagrams - Part 1 of 1_qtp.mp4" -o b.flv
```

Still not sure how to get the entire video. Will update the answer if I figure out!

--Edit

Just had to increase the buffer size!!
and its working! :)

```
-R --buffer 2000
```